# Statistical test for sampling discrete objects from urn

Tags: r, statistical-significance, discrete-data

I have data that looks like this:

```
  selected_genes <- c("A","X","Y")
  pooled_genes <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", 
"M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", 
"Z")
```

The question I want to answer is that if we pick 3 genes from `pooled_genes` how likely that `selected_genes` is obtained.

What's the appropriate statistical test to obtain p-value for that?

Comment: Does the order of selected_genes play a role? Can genes be picked twice? Can selected_genes contain the same gene twice? Please extend your question, so that answers are either right or wrong and not depending on interpretation.

Comment: @Bernhard Thanks a lot. Order of selected genes doesn't matter. Yes the genes can be picked twice. No selected genes cannot contain the same gene twice.

Comment: Oh sorry for the second comment. As "A" is in the selected_genes but not in the pooled_genes, the answer is easy: It is not likely at all.

Comment: @Bernhard Can you elaborate. We (my boss) need a p-value to justify.

Comment: @neversaint, what Bernhard meant is that gene "A" in "selected_genes" does not occur in "pooled_genes", thus "A" cannot be picked, and the corresponding probability is zero.

Comment: @hakanc @Bernhard Oops sorry. I fixed my OP to include `A` in pooled.

Comment: @neversaint, additionally, a statistical test can use a p-value for evaluation, not the other way around https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the order of picking does not matter, and genes are sampled with replacement from pooled genes (you dont delete a sample from pooled genes after it has been picked), the corresponding distribution is the [Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

From the distribution and assigning probabilities of picking genes, $p_i$, $i \in \{A,B,...\}$, the p-value can be calculated given an observation.

Comment: `c("A","X","Y")` is the observation. How can I get the p-value with R code?